# How to a use a variable in the date() function

Tags: php

If the following code  I want to use variables instead of the actual date.

```
echo date('z', strtotime('13  may '));
```

How do I use the variables:

```
$month = "may";
$day = "13";
```

Answer (score 0):

The [String Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) section in the official PHP doc will help you.

```
$month = "may";
$day = "13";

echo date('z', strtotime($day . '  ' . $month . ' '));
```